# How to make media queries work in Next.js 13.4?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, media-queries

I have a next.js project where the media queries don't work. This is what I have done so far:

- I have added my queries in "styles.module.css" and "global.css" and imported these in layout.js
- I have added the viewport meta tag under a Head tag and included this in layout.js

This is my current layout.js file:

```
import "./globals.css";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import "./styles.module.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Head from "next/head";
import Script from "next/script";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "My website",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
          ></meta>

          <title>My Website</title>

          <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            type="image/x-icon"
            href="/images/favicon.ico"
          />
        </Head>
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </>
  );
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing and/or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

afaik, there is no reason to include the viewport metadata, title, or favicon links.  If you're using the app router, Next has it's own cleaner mechanism for doing those things via the Metadata api and a metadata variable exported variable from your root layout file.  Since you're already using that, you should include all those things in the metadata export.  If you want to see what's available, look at type Metadata.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata

Regarding your responsivity issue, you'd have to supply more information about what is not working.  As it is, you've not supplied much code that relates to that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it

This code didn't work for me:

```
.burgerBtn {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 22px;
  @media (max-width: 1100px) {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

And i changed it:

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .burgerBtn{
    display: flex
  }
}
```

and the problem was solved